# Extracting value for one dictionary key in Pandas based on another in the same dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

This is from an R guy.

I have this mess in a Pandas column: `data['crew']`.

```
array(["[{'credit_id': '54d5356ec3a3683ba0000039', 'department': 'Production', 'gender': 1, 'id': 494, 'job': 'Casting', 'name': 'Terri Taylor', 'profile_path': None}, {'credit_id': '56407fa89251417055000b58', 'department': 'Sound', 'gender': 0, 'id': 6745, 'job': 'Music Editor', 'name': 'Richard Henderson', 'profile_path': None}, {'credit_id': '5789212392514135d60025fd', 'department': 'Production', 'gender': 2, 'id': 9250, 'job': 'Executive In Charge Of Production', 'name': 'Jeffrey Stott', 'profile_path': None}, {'credit_id': '57892074c3a36835fa002886', 'department': 'Costume & Make-Up', 'gender': 0, 'id': 23783, 'job': 'Makeup Artist', 'name': 'Heather Plott', 'profile_path': None}
```

It goes on for quite some time. Each new dict starts with a `credit_id` field. One sell can hold several dicts in an array.

Assume I want the names of all `Casting` directors, as shown in the first entry. I need to check check the `job` entry in every dict and, if it's `Casting`, grab what's in the `name` field and store it in my data frame in `data['crew']`.

I tried several strategies, then backed off and went for something simple. 
Running the following shut me down, so I can't even access a simple field. How can I get this done in Pandas.

```
for row in data.head().iterrows():
    if row['crew'].job == 'Casting':
        print(row['crew'])
```

EDIT: Error Message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-aa6183fdf7ac> in <module>()
      1 for row in data.head().iterrows():
----> 2     if row['crew'].job == 'Casting':
      3         print(row['crew'])

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

EDIT: Code used to get the array of dict (strings?) in the first place.

```
def convert_JSON(data_as_string):
    try:
        dict_representation = ast.literal_eval(data_as_string)
        return dict_representation
    except ValueError:
        return []

data["crew"] = data["crew"].map(lambda x: sorted([d['name'] if d['job'] == 'Casting' else '' for d in convert_JSON(x)])).map(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))
```

Comment: what is your desired output? are you trying to overwrite `data['crew']`? that's what it sounds like based on your description...

Comment: Hi there, can you add the error you are getting? One thing I can see (but cannot tell if it's a typo), the array is an array or `str` not an array of dictionaries, so doesn't look like you can access the key/values from it. If this is the case, `literal_eval()` from ast [helpers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers) might help

Comment: Yes. That's it!

Comment: @nickthefreak I actually used that to unpack the str that contained the initial data object. Are you suggesting I use it again? I'll post the code.

Comment: @Ryan i cannot tell for sure to be honest, but the format `array(["[..]")` hints in that direction. Check what the type of the first element of the array is; if it's str, you need to unpack probably.

Answer (score 1):

To create a DataFrame from your sample data, write:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
  { 'credit_id': '54d5356ec3a3683ba0000039', 'department': 'Production',
    'gender': 1, 'id': 494, 'job': 'Casting', 'name': 'Terri Taylor',
    'profile_path': None},
  { 'credit_id': '56407fa89251417055000b58', 'department': 'Sound',
    'gender': 0, 'id': 6745, 'job': 'Music Editor',
    'name': 'Richard Henderson', 'profile_path': None},
  { 'credit_id': '5789212392514135d60025fd', 'department': 'Production',
    'gender': 2, 'id': 9250, 'job': 'Executive In Charge Of Production',
    'name': 'Jeffrey Stott', 'profile_path': None},
  { 'credit_id': '57892074c3a36835fa002886', 'department': 'Costume & Make-Up',
    'gender': 0, 'id': 23783, 'job': 'Makeup Artist',
    'name': 'Heather Plott', 'profile_path': None}])
```

Then you can get your data with a single instruction:

```
df[df.job == 'Casting'].name
```

The result is:

```
0    Terri Taylor
Name: name, dtype: object
```

The above result is *Pandas* *Series* object with names found.
In this case, `0` is the index value for the record found and
`Terri Taylor` is the name of (the only in your data) Casting Director.

## Edit

If you want just a **list** (not *Series*), write:

```
df[df.job == 'Casting'].name.tolist()
```

The result is `['Terri Taylor']` - just a list.

I think, both my solutions should be quicker than "ordinary" loop
based on `iterrows()`.

Checking the execution time, you may try also yet another solution:

```
df.query("job == 'Casting'").name.tolist()
```

==========

And as far as your code is concerned:

`iterrows()` returns each time a **pair** containing:

- the key of the current row,
- a named tuple - the **content** of this row.

So your loop should look something like:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1].job == 'Casting':
        print(row[1]['name'])
```

You can not write `row[1].name` because it refers to the **index** value
(here we have a collision with default attributes of the named tuple).

Comment: May end up going this way if a quicker method does not become apparent.